# How to dynamically chose a transform function based on current observable in project reactor?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Hello dear reactive programmers, I started to learn project reactor but I still struggle to figure out what operator to use when. I figured out, that if I want to have reusable parts to define a reactor flow, I can use the **transform** operator. What I would like to achieve is to use a certain implementation of such a flow function based on the current observables context. For a Mono flow, I came up with this, but I am very unsure, if it is a good solution:

So here is a part of the flow

```
class CloudeventOverDelegatorRoute(
  val fromHttpToDelegatorRoute: FromHttpToDelegatorRoute,
  val delegatorProvider: DelegatorProvider,
  val fromDelegatorToHttpRoute: FromDelegatorToHttpRoute
): MessageRoute<HttpBaseMessage, HttpResponseMessage> {

  override fun isHandlerFor(context: RouteContext): Boolean {
    return fromHttpToDelegatorRoute.isHandlerFor(context)
      && fromDelegatorToHttpRoute.isHandlerFor(context)
  }

  override fun buildPipeline(input: Mono<RoutableMessage<HttpBaseMessage>>): Mono<RoutableMessage<HttpResponseMessage>> {
    var dynamicallyDeterminedDelegator: Delegator? = null
    return input.transform {
      fromHttpToDelegatorRoute.buildPipeline(input)
    }.handle<RoutableMessage<InternalMessage>> { t, u ->
      dynamicallyDeterminedDelegator = delegatorProvider.provideDelegatorFor(t.routeContext)
      u.next(t)
      u.complete()
    }.transform {
      dynamicallyDeterminedDelegator!!.sendDelegated(it)
    }.transform { fromDelegatorToHttpRoute.buildPipeline(it) }
  }

}
```

Here is the dynamic selection logic

```
interface DelegatorProvider {

  fun provideDelegatorFor(context: RouteContext): Delegator

}

class FirstMatchDelegatorProvider(
  private val delegators: List<Delegator>
): DelegatorProvider {

  override fun provideDelegatorFor(context: RouteContext): Delegator {
    return delegators.firstOrNull {
      it.isHandlerFor(context)
    }?: throw IllegalStateException("No Delegator route available for context: $context")
  }

}
```

And this is the delegator providing an essential sub-part of the whole flow

```
interface Delegator {

  fun isHandlerFor(context: RouteContext): Boolean

  fun sendDelegated(input: Mono<RoutableMessage<InternalMessage>>): Mono<RoutableMessage<InternalStatusMessage>>

}
```

What do you think? How would you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this approach is problematic because it relies on **shared state** (the `dynamicallyDeterminedDelegator` variable). If multiple subscribers subscribe to the returned `Mono`, they could overwrite each other delegator. Maybe that (multiple subscriptions) can't happen in your application, but this is a very bad habit to get into in any case.

looks like you can derive a `delegator` out of a `RoutableMessage<InternalMessage>` , and that you don't really need to retain that delegator.

the easiest way to resolve and apply the delegator to the routableMessage in one go is simply to use `flatMap`. see the (pseudo) java code below:

```
.flatMap(routableMessage -> {
    val delegator = delegatorProvider.provideDelegatorFor(routableMessage.routeContext);
    return delegator.sendDelegated(routableMessage);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Simon, thx for pointing that out, especially that delegator is fully dependent of the RoutableMessage state. I still have some trouble to wrap my head around assembly and processing time, but I am getting there :). I finally ended up with a flat map solution.